# How to use Lead in Update SQL command

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, lead

This works with `SELECT`:

```
(LEAD(AltCode,2) OVER (ORDER BY AltCode) ) from [clroot].[Material]
```

but not with Update

```
USE [MEKON-EPE]

UPDATE [clroot].Material
SET String1 = (LEAD(AltCode, 2) OVER (ORDER BY AltCode))
FROM [clroot].[Material]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

I want to update a specific column with the value of the value of next 2 columns.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Storing such a value is a bad idea here as if the value ever changes the value in the column is out of date. You should be using a `VIEW` here.

Comment: Thom A is correct.   That said, if you must, you can update via a CTE.   Sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on my comment

```
with cte as (
  Select *
        ,NewVal = LEAD(AltCode,2) OVER (ORDER BY AltCode)
 from [clroot].[Material
)
Update cte
 set String1 = NewVal
```